# forgot password

Tags: password, username

I requested a new password at /wp/wp-admin, I enter my user name and it said a new password has been sent, though hours later nothing is on my e-mail.

How else may I log into WP with new user name and password ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset it in phpmyadmin if it's your own site by using a utility to replace it in the database. Search for 'Wordpress password generator' and this should show you the way.

If it's not your site, contact the administrator or check your spam.

Obviously if there's a site admin you know, get them to reset it!

EDIT: Also double check your email address...this is the #1 cause of it not landing. If you aren't sure if it was right in the first place, try registering again. If it works, you mistyped your email first time around and copy-pasted it to confirm without checking ;-).

Comment: Also, check your junk folder.